# Rotated an PNG image with PHP. How to remove the black lines around the original?

Tags: php, image, png, transparency, rotation

I am using PHP to rotate an PNG image, with a transparant background. But whatever I try, there are still some black lines around the original image.

How do I remove the black lines. Everything else works fine. The image is transparant, the image is rotated, the new corners are also transparant. Just the black lines around the original square (which is rotated) are annoying me.

I use this code:

```
$angle = -100;
header('Content-type: image/png');  

$image = 'http://mapning.com/img/plane.png';
$file = imagecreatefrompng($image);

$rotate = imagerotate($file, $angle, 0);


imageSaveAlpha($rotate, true);
ImageAlphaBlending($rotate, false);

$transparentColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($rotate, 200, 200, 200, 127);
imagefill($rotate, 0, 0, $transparentColor);

imagepng($rotate);
```

I found my answer here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php#47985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better use imagick
[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) is an extension for PHP

Or if you want with GD see here
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php#46338